# How to use pop on 2d arrays?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a card deck of 30 cards and take out one at a time and divide them between two players by using pop but I don't know why pop isn't working, why isn't my pop working

I have tried to use `.remove` but my teacher says pop must be used and I don't know why pop isn't working

```
card_deck = [["yellow",1],["yellow",2],["yellow",3],["yellow",4],    ["yellow",5],["yellow",6],["yellow",7],["yellow",8],["yellow",9],     ["yellow",10],
["red",1],["red",2],["red",3],["red",4],["red",5],["red",6],["red",7],    ["red",8],["red",9],["red",10],
["black",1],["black",2],["black",3],["black",4],["black",5],["black",6],    ["black",7],["black",8],["black",9],["black",10]]

cardies = 30

while True:
  if cardies > 0:
    u1_card = random.choice(card_deck)
    u2_card = random.choice(card_deck)
    print ("player 1's card is", u1_card)
    print("player 2's card is", u2_card)
    card_deck.pop(u1_card)
    card_deck.pop(u2_card)
    len(card_deck) - 1
  if u1_card == u2_card:
    card_deck.pop
```

I expect the card deck (`card_deck`) to be shuffled randomly and then to be divided one card at a time to each player (`u1_card`, `u2_card`) until there are no cards left.

Comment: What do you mean "isn't working"?

Comment: when its gets to line  ,card_deck.pop(u1_card), it gives an error saying list cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: Please share more information, like expected output and the output your getting now.

Comment: Well, that's because what `pop` does is remove (and return) the element at a given index. You need to pass an `int` representing an index to it, not a `list`. You probably want just `pop()`, which removes the last (conceptually the "top") element.

Answer (score 0):

You want to call the function so brackets are necessary. It should be:

```
card = card_deck.pop() # for your last line of code
```

Also, `pop()` requires an index argument, so `card_deck.pop(u1_card)` will not work. You can get the index with `.index()` so

```
card_deck.pop(card_deck.index(u1_card))
```

Also I think you mean to be updating `cardies` with this line: `len(card_deck) - 1`

```
cardies -= 1 # you might have to change this to 2, to get the desired result because you are popping 2 cards per loop iteration
```

You should also have a condition to end the while loop otherwise you will encounter an error when the list is empty, something like:

```
while len(card_deck) != 0:
    ...
```